# Calculating threshold by the "slower version" of Otsu's method

Tags: java, image-processing, image-thresholding

[This site](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html) gives an implementation of the approach with **between class variance.** I want, however, to do it with **within class variance**(unfortunately I can't post the formula, but you can see it on the site), which is considered to be slower. This is my approach:

```
double varb,varf = 0;
int sum,wB,wF,treshold = 0 
double varMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
for (int t=0 ; t<256; t++) {
    for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
        sum+= i*hist[i];
    }
    for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
        wB += hist[i];
    }
    sumB += (float) (t * histo[t]);
    wF = N - wB;
    double mB =(double) N*sumB / wB; // Mean Background
    double mF = (double) N*(sum - sumB) / wF; // sum is the sum of all grey values

    for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
        varb += (i-mB)*(i-mB)*(hist[i]/N)/wB;
    }
    for(int i =t+1; i <256; i++) {
        varb += (i-mF)*(i-mF)*(hist[i]/N)/wF;
    }
    double var = wB*varb/N + wF * varf/N;
    if (var < varMin) {  //checks for the smallest variance
        varMin = var;
        threshold = t;
    }
}
```

I am getting always zero. What can I do?

Comment: That code seems to be incomplete, what is eg the initial value of `varMin`?

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious bug in the code in all the 4 loops that you use to accumulate values for a given `t`:

```
for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
    sum+= i*hist[i];
}
for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
    wB += hist[i];
}
```

`sum` and `wB` are not reset before these loops, meaning that, for each new `t`, you add these values to those computed for previous `t`. Correct is:

```
sum = 0;
wB = 0;
for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
    sum+= i*hist[i];
    wB += hist[i];    // (also no need for looping twice over `hist`)
}
```

The other two loops:

```
for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
    varb += (i-mB)*(i-mB)*(hist[i]/N)/wB;
}
for(int i =t+1; i <256; i++) {
    varb += (i-mF)*(i-mF)*(hist[i]/N)/wF;
}
```

Here the same happens, but also you use `varb` twice, and never use `varf`. Correct:

```
varb = 0;
varf = 0;
for(int i =1; i <=t; i++) {
    varb += (i-mB)*(i-mB)*(hist[i]/N)/wB;
}
for(int i =t+1; i <256; i++) {
    varf += (i-mF)*(i-mF)*(hist[i]/N)/wF;
}
```

Your code doesn't show where you compute `sumGrayvalues` and `mitt`, let's assume you did those right. Then you can also see that `sum` and `wB` can be computed from the previous iteration of `t`, by adding just a single element from `hist`.

(I haven't run the code, I don't do Java, so I'm not sure if there are other issues.)